# Understanding Spark alongside Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

In the set up I have, both Hadoop and Spark are running on the same network but on different nodes. We can run Spark alongside your existing Hadoop cluster by just launching it as a separate service. Will it show any improvement in performance?

I have thousands of files around 10 GB loaded into HDFS.

I have 8 nodes for Hadoop, 1 master and 5 workers for Spark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the worker is on the same node, we have the advantage of Locality. You can launch your service alongside hadoop as well.